# Algorithm selection

Tags: time-series

I have a dataset as below:

```
Start time          end time    value 
1                   4           0.6    
2                   4           0.4
3                   4           0.312
4                   4           0.01
```

Like this, I have measurements made on different days.
I want to predict the end time. This time is when value reaches minimum.

Does this comes under time series prediction? Or any idea which algorithm works?